# Injecting JpaRepository: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I have problem with properly injecting JpaRepository to data provider.

I put @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in my [EpisodieApiApplication.class](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie-api/blob/master/application/configuration/src/main/java/pl/hypeapp/episodie/EpisodieApiApplication.java) located in package:

> package pl.hypeapp.episodie;

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pl.hypeapp.episodie.configuration")
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class EpisodieApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EpisodieApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(EpisodieApiApplication.class);
     }
}
```

[DatabaseDataProviderConfiguration.class](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie-api/blob/master/application/configuration/src/main/java/pl/hypeapp/episodie/configuration/dataprovider/DatabaseDataProviderConfiguration.java) located in pacakage

> package pl.hypeapp.episodie.configuration.dataprovider;

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseDataProviderConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public TvShowDatabaseProvider tvShowDatabaseProvider(TvShowRepository tvShowRepository) {
   return new TvShowDatabaseProvider(tvShowRepository);
   }
}
```

[TvShowRepository.class](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie-api/blob/master/application/dataproviders/src/main/java/pl/hypeapp/episodie/dataproviders/database/TvShowRepository.java) located in package

> package pl.hypeapp.episodie.dataproviders.database;

```
public interface TvShowRepository extends JpaRepository<TvShow, String> {
}
```

My databaseprovider in module application/dataproviders/database
[DatabaseDataProvider.class](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie-api/blob/master/application/dataproviders/src/main/java/pl/hypeapp/episodie/dataproviders/database/TvShowDatabaseProvider.java)

```
public class TvShowDatabaseProvider implements DoesTvShowExist, GetTvShowFromDatabase, InsertTvShowToDatabase {

    private final TvShowRepository tvShowRepository;

    public TvShowDatabaseProvider(TvShowRepository tvShowRepository) {
        this.tvShowRepository = tvShowRepository;
    }
}
```

[TvShow.class](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie-api/blob/master/application/core/src/main/java/pl/hypeapp/core/entity/tvmaze/TvShow.java) located in package:

> package pl.hypeapp.core.entity.tvmaze;

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@Entity
public class TvShow {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer id;
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'tvShowDatabaseProvider' defined in class path resource [pl/hypeapp/episodie/configuration/dataprovider/DatabaseDataProviderConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tvShowDatabaseProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tvShowRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class pl.hypeapp.core.entity.tvmaze.TvShow

Whole code at [github](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie-api) but its incomplete and may not work due to missing classes

Comment: It is saying it does not know about your entity. Are you setting a base package when using `@EnableJpaRepositories`? If your entities are not in a sub package of your `@Application`, you may need to use `@EntityScan`

Comment: Can you post the code for your `SpiringApplication` class as well? Also, show us the package names for these classes like `TvShowRepository`

Comment: @javaguy I edited question. You can look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not scanning your entities. You could use `"pl.hypeapp"` as basePackages for `@EnableJpaRepository` or use `@EntityScan`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "pl.hypeapp.episodie.configuration")
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"pl.hypeapp.episodie.dataproviders"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"pl.hypeapp.core.entity"})
public class EpisodieApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EpisodieApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(EpisodieApiApplication.class);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution works. Also I needed put @Id annotations in my entity class.

Answer (score 2):

You are using constructor injection for injecting `TvShowRepository` bean and `@Autowired` is missing for the constructor of your `TvShowDatabaseProvider`, so you need to add it as shown below:

```
public class TvShowDatabaseProvider implements 
             DoesTvShowExist, GetTvShowFromDatabase, 
             InsertTvShowToDatabase {

    private final TvShowRepository tvShowRepository;

    @Autowired //add this
    public TvShowDatabaseProvider(TvShowRepository tvShowRepository) {
        this.tvShowRepository = tvShowRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, you will get the error because it is nothing to do with `@EnableJpaRepository` packaging, because your Repository class is already in the scanning list, So **the problem is with wiring the bean**, so look at the updated answer now