# Can't inject repository in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is my repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Group, Integer> {}
```

This is how I tried to use it in my service class:

```java
@Service
public class GroupService {
    private final GroupRepository groupRepository;

    @Autowired
    public GroupService(GroupRepository groupRepository) {
        this.groupRepository = groupRepository;
    }
```

Got this error :`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'groupService' defined in file [/Users/nathanxuan/Files/Project/ratingApp/target/classes/com/xjy/service/GroupService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepository' defined in com.xjy.mapper.GroupRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.xjy.pojo.Group`

Does anyone know why this is happening? When I commented out the repository class everything works fine (I have another mapper class and that one also works).

-------edit-----------
This is the structure of my app:

[image]

Comment: Did you use the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation on a Spring Configuration class? If you already enabled JPARepositories, please share the full stack trace.

Comment: Are the Repository and the service in the same package or a sub-package level as the main Application class?

Comment: @Fabien No I didn't but my project doesn't even have a configuration class. Where do you typically add that?

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov the Service class is in `.service` and `GroupRepository` is in `.mapper`

Comment: Try to follow section 3.5 : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-annotations

Comment: @Nathan Try with adding this @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="<repository package name>") on the main method level
You can check also - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43240386/7357959

Comment: But are you using Spring Boot with a Spring-data-jpa starter? Then this conf should be optional.

Comment: @Fabien Hey if you're talking about the maven dependency, yeah I've included `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Comment: @TsvetoslavTsvetkov Tried it and got another error `A component required a bean of type 'com.xjy.mapper.GroupRepository' that could not be found.`

Comment: Can you share your main class package structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the model class **Group**, it needs the **Entity** annotation since you are using JPA. Try out this:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Group {
    ....
}
```

Note: **@Data @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor** comes from Lombok, so if you're not using it, just create regular Getter and Setter

Comment: Thanks man! This solved it! I didn't include the `@Entity` annotation. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @Repository from your repository. By extending from JpaRepository should be enough.

Unless you really need a setter injection defining your repository in the service like this should also be fine and more concise.

```
@Autowired
private GroupRepository groupRepository;
```

Comment: Constructor injection (which the asker has used) should be preferred over field injection.

Comment: Depends on the scenario. For the majority of use cases constructor injection is just adding boiler plate code. And if you have 100 beans to inject…I never use constructor injection.

Comment: If you have 100 beans to inject, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Exactly. Throw @Autowired on it and keep going. Keep your beans stateless and you wont worry about immutability.